Measure gaps in support of histogram/probability distributions
I have a distribution of a Groundtruth (green graph) that I would like to learn using xgboost. The red graph in the figure below shows the distribution of xgboost's learned predictions. By the way, distributions are that of a stock's realized volatility.
As you can see in the green graph, there are "GAPS" in the support of the Groundtruth where there are no data points i.e. white spaces. I would like have a quantity that can measure these gaps into a single value so that I can compare this quantity for different distributions. I know that I could take log transformation to make this distribution more compact with fewer gaps.
However, my goal is to show that xgboost predictions are poor whenever these gaps are very wide or there are many gaps in the distribution. This is because xgboost basically does averaging of the training set's Groundtruth to make predictions. So if the inputs to the average come from intervals separated by wide gaps then they might lead to poor predictions that lie in-between the intervals.
Note that I can keep the bin size constant (1000) whenever I make comparison between different histograms/distributions. What would be a suitable quantity to measure these gaps and how can I achieve that in python? Is there mathematical name to these "GAPS"?
Thanks.


How about for each distribution

order the groundtruth in ascending order.
2)Take up to the 75th percentile to avoid the outliers.
Take first differences
order the first differences in descending order
take the sum of first differences up to the 50th percentile. Let's call this quantity, total_gap
rank the total_gap for each distribution to identify distributions with most gaps


What about these gaps do you want to measure? You could simply count them in at least two ways (number of gap and size of gap).

Actually, even if I keep the number of bins the same they will not be comparable because each distributions' groundtruth have different ranges (i.e. Min max values) so it's better to sum up the size of the gaps.
